# How can I change the cardview border color dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, cardview

I would like to change the border color of my cardview based on the content.Is it possible to reach somehow the xml file from the recyclerview adapter and change the color?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your desired state. You can color CardView *background* by `setCardBackgroundColor`. But there is no straightforward means to color the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> xml file from the recyclerview adapter and change the color?

No. XML is read only. And you do not need to touch it, but use i.f. `findViewById()`, find your card view, and use its methods to alter the color.

Comment: Then I would like to modify my question: how can I set only a colored border for my cardview? Which methods should I use in this case? Btw thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using the `Databinding` library.
Let's say that your content is a `User` and you need to change the color of your `CardView` if he/she is an adult or a child. So you can pass the object in your Activity or Fragment like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   MainActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
   User user = new User("Test", "User");
   binding.setUser(user);
}
```

And then, add the `data` tag and the variable in your `XML` file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>

   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     android:background="@{user.isAdult ? @color/yellow : @color/gray }"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.firstName}"/>
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

If you want to know more, check the documentation : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html?hl=pt-br